# Laravel Vue disable input field with checkbox

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Html input field and checkbox

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="password" id="password" 
:disabled="auto_password">
<b-checkbox name="auto_generate" class="m-t-15" v-model="auto_password">Auto 
Generate Password</b-checkbox>`
```

Vue.js script

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        auto_password: true
    }
 });
```

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: this code work as expected, here you are missing the `<div id="app">` to instantiate vue

Comment: [Vue warn]: Property or method "auto_password" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: Wrap your html code in `<div id="app">`